# checking windows time sync from 2 computers with different times

Tags: time-synchronization, w32time

I have 2 domain controllers, that are NOT on the same forest (they are on the same network though)

I am trying to have both of them sync from the same time sync server (time.windows.com) so times will be approx the same.

I have a major off set of about 30 seconds between them, already when I click:

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com /samples:5 /data
```

I run this command with half a second apart between both computers, and these are the results I get:

```
computer 1
Tracking time.windows.com [65.55.21.17:123].
Collecting 5 samples.
The current time is 3/22/2012 2:01:56 PM.
14:01:56, +26.3561536s
14:01:58, +26.3449049s
14:02:00, +26.3570688s
14:02:02, +26.3536394s
14:02:04, +26.3502308s


computer 2
The current time is 3/22/2012 14:02:21 (local time).
14:02:21, -00.0007888s
14:02:23, +00.0034772s
14:02:26, +00.0077185s
14:02:28, +00.0041969s
14:02:30, +00.0006753s
```

There is an approx 26 seconds diff, how do I solve this?
These 26s are all printed in the report, but not sure where/how

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how these domains are currently configured to obtain dependable time.

Run

```
w32tm /monitor
```

on a DC in each domain to see the current delays and configured parents

and

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com /reliable:YES
```

to make it force sync with a chosen source - and all other DCs sync from that one.

You should

w32tm /resync

on all other DCs after setting a source manually.

Comment: thanks, running this on one DC prompts an error: C:\Users\usr115040>w32tm /resync
Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.  I will sort this, and continue.